# Mock external class in Rails controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I have a Rails 3 app that I am testing with RSpec. I have a controller using external class `MustMock` as

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def myaction
    mockme = MustMock.new
    @foobar = mockme.do_something
  end
end
```

How can I best mock the instance of `MustMock` in my controller spec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
describe FooController do
  specify :myaction do
    MustMock.should_receive(:new)
            .and_return(stub :do_something => :something)
    get :myaction
    assigns[:foobar].should == :something
  end
end
```

Comment: +1, I like the form of this block a lot. I'm going to copy your style! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
it "does something in myaction" do
    my_stub = stub()
    my_stub.should_receive(:do_something).once.and_return(:foobar)
    MustMock.stub(:new => my_stub)
    get :myaction
    response.should be_success
end
```

Comment: A minor quibble - I'd tend to put the `response.should be_success` in a shared_example, as it will be so common to want that for a page.  YMMV

Comment: Yes, there are several ways the test could be improved. I suspect the OP's controller action is more complex and s/he distilled the problem into the minimum demonstrable action.

Comment: totally agree, I did really mean minor :)